# Can a static page read environment variable?

Tags: html, nginx, static-pages

Currently I have a nginx server running in a container and want to display a static page when someone access https://example.com/showname/.
The static page need to show the pod name get from the environment variable, is there a way to do this?

my env var name:deployment_env and below is static page code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test NGINX passed</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>deploy_env</h1>
        <h1><span id="deploy_env" style="display: block;"></span></h1>
        <script>
            var env = window.env;
            var deploy = document.querySelector('#deploy_env');
            deploy.textContent = env.deployment_env;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [official nginx docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx), there is an easy way since the image contains [envsubst functionality](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/nginx#using-environment-variables-in-nginx-configuration-new-in-119) for quite some time now.

1. Here is the solution as you wished. It uses the envsubst feature to replace the environment variable in a file called *env.js.template*. It will be substituted and written into the html folder when nginx starts.

**showname.html**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test NGINX passed</title>
        <script src="/env.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>deploy_env</h1>
        <h1><span id="deploy_env" style="display: block;"></span></h1>
        <script>
            var env = window.env;
            var deploy = document.querySelector('#deploy_env');
            deploy.textContent = env.deployment_env;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**env.js.template**

```js
window.env = {
  "deployment_env": "${deployment_env}"
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1

ENV NGINX_ENVSUBST_TEMPLATE_DIR=/usr/share/nginx/templates \
    NGINX_ENVSUBST_OUTPUT_DIR=/usr/share/nginx/html

COPY env.js.template /usr/share/nginx/templates/
COPY showname.html /usr/share/nginx/html/showname/index.html
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
services:
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      deployment_env: production
    ports:
      - 8000:80/tcp
```

2. In your case, you could have it even simpler by leaving out javascript altogether and making the html page itself an nginx template:

**showname.html.template**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test NGINX passed</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>deploy_env</h1>
        <h1><span id="deploy_env" style="display: block;">${deployment_env}</span></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1

ENV NGINX_ENVSUBST_TEMPLATE_DIR=/usr/share/nginx/templates \
    NGINX_ENVSUBST_OUTPUT_DIR=/usr/share/nginx/html

COPY showname.html.template /usr/share/nginx/templates/showname/index.html.template
```

I admit that this functionality in the image was supposed to be used for configuration files only. If you want a cleaner solution, you might want to adjust the docker entrypoint to add a different envsubst usage.